# How to call an event when my Input's value changes with JavaScript Date Picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is an input which is Date Picker.
It is impossible to type in the input, everybody can only pick a date by mouse.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QQeM.png)

How can I call an event when the user changes Date ?

Here is HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12">
    <label for="homeWorkStartDate">From: </label>
    <input type="text" id="homeWorkStartDate" class="pdate form-control" />
    <input type="hidden" id="txtHomeWorkStartDate" />
    <script>
        var objCal1 = new AMIB.persianCalendar('homeWorkStartDate', {
            extraInputID: 'txtHomeWorkStartDate',
            extraInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        });
    </script>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12">
    <label for="homeWorkEndDate">To: </label>
    <input type="text" id="homeWorkEndDate" class="pdate form-control" />
    <input type="hidden" id="txtHomeWorkEndDate" />
    <script>
        var objCal1 = new AMIB.persianCalendar('homeWorkEndDate', {
            extraInputID: 'txtHomeWorkEndDate',
            extraInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Here is what I tried but doesn't work:

```
$("#homeWorkStartDate,#homeWorkEndDate").on('input propertychange',function(){
    alert("hi");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try something like this ?

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    onSelect: function () {
        alert('hello');
    }
})
```

Comment: I replace ("#datepicker") to ("#homeWorkStartDate, #homeWorkEndDate"), it doesn't work

Comment: @Masoud does it show any error or something ?

Comment: No there is no any error in console.

Comment: @Masoud https://jsfiddle.net/w09cnyvb/ I tried something let me know if it is right.

Comment: Yes that's the answer, thanks

Comment: @Masoud make this answer useful please